# DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, updated_at) AS Diff, COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I just cant wrap my head arround this :(

I am trying to output 3 diffrent results from my column "Diff"

<1 <3 and <7

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, updated_at) AS Diff, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY Diff
```

But I actually need only to output 3 columns, amounts <1, <3 and <7

I hope someone can help

Comment: <1 is also <3 which is also <7 did you mean <1 ,>=1 and <3, >=3 and <7? And do you need  >=7?

Comment: yes :)  Tims query works fine for me, but this would make it perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, updated_at) < 1 THEN 1 END) AS diff_lt_1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, updated_at) >= 1 AND
                    DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, updated_at) < 3 THEN 1 END) AS diff_1_to_3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, updated_at) >= 3 AND
                    DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, updated_at) < 7 THEN 1 END) AS diff_3_to_7,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, updated_at) >= 7 THEN 1 END) AS diff_gt_7
FROM Table;
```

It isn't actually clear by which column(s) your should be doing a `GROUP BY`.  We can modify the above query if you reveal sample data showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wow, this is working like a charm :) Thank you so much !  How can I modify this, so it doesnt "double count" because, it will now show in <7 also the <1

Comment: @Intercept0r I will tell you that typically you would also be grouping by some column, and then getting these diffs for each group.  In this case, you are getting them across the entire table.  If that's what you want, then you're done.  If not, then show some sample data.

Comment: The entiry table is fine, I also dont need a group ;)

Comment: Sure :) Can you help with the "double count" also?, i cant figure out how to place AND

Comment: I don't know what double count means to you.

Comment: Well, now in <1 it shows everything <1, thats fine, but in <3 it also show eveything <1 but it should be <3 and >1

Comment: Bingo, your the Man :) Thanks!